# Suggest linked questions in vote-to-close dialogue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Sometimes people will mention possible duplicate questions in a comment, and these get put into the Linked sidebar. But when I vote to close the question, this question doesn't appear in the suggestions, it only has the first few questions from the Related sidebar, and questions that have been put in previous close-as-duplicate votes.