# scan comments for links when closing as duplicate

Tags: feature-request

Occassionally, a user will post a comment:

```
possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/....
```

However, they themselves won't vote to close.  For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069127/python-configparser-module-rename-a-section) from earlier today.

I take a look at the possible duplicate, then I go back and take a look at the original.  Lo and behold, they are similar enough that I would consider them duplicates.  Now, if I go to close, much of the time, stackoverflow doesn't suggest that the linked question in the comments is a duplicate, so I have to close the "close question" dialog, go to the other question, copy the url, go back to the original question and go through the vote to close procedure again.  This seems like an unnecessary hassle when the url is already there in the comments.  Would it be possible to scan the comments for urls and somehow determine which of those are possible duplicates?

Comment: He posted it as a comment b/c he doesn't have enough rep to vote-to-close. And checkout the 'Linked' section on the right of that question.

Comment: @MikeB -- fair enough.  That still doesn't help me when I go to close the question as a dupe -- I still need to remember to copy the url to my clipboard first which is inconvenient.

Comment: @mgilson The problem here is that the user posted a comment instead of flagging the question as a duplicate. If they had flagged, a comment would have been posted automatically and the duplicate would be available in the close dialog.

Comment: @Yannis so that functionality is great, but as MikeB said the user doesn't have a lot of rep. So what are the chances of the user knowing that functionality exists? How do you suggest we make users aware of that functionality? Cause I run into the above problem a metric crap ton in the `javascript` tag.

Comment: @ryan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069127/python-configparser-module-rename-a-section#comment21192140_15069127 - And if you find yourself repeating such comments a lot, then: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @ryan -- precisely.  I'm a high rep user and *I* didn't even know how it worked exactly ... :)

Comment: Well, each user who can flag is already pointed to this: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Ironically, this appears to be a duplicate of [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164228).